# How to check file names under two triggers in one logic app

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

I'm using two triggers in one logic app 1.recurrence 2.when a file is created or modified under recurrence two parallel actions will be there it will run daily under when a file is created or modified trigger there parallel actions will be there so if one action under when a file is created or modified trigger excecute reaming all are failed also if recurrence actions will be excecute reaming actions will failed so how can I overcome these situation finall i want i my logic app will execute successfully NOTE:6 parallel actions will maintain different paths.

Comment: Can you please make your question more readable with proper sentences?

Comment: Like Peter said, upadte your question to be clearer and secondly, show us the flow with the issues illustrated.

Comment: Ok  simple how to check the file names under when a file is created or modified trigger 9 parallel actions will be there so if one file will upload in one path that action only excecute reaming all are excute false NOTE 9 actions will maintain different paths

Comment: First will try above case

Answer (score 0):

Below is something that you can try instead of using 9 parallel triggers in the flow. I would recommend you to use one `When a file is created or modified (properties only)` and then use switch action for 9 different paths. Below is the flow of my logic app.

[image]

Comment: @James Yes it is

Comment: Under 9 actions 3 of the actions are recurrence actions those 3 actions will run daily just we can add recurrence code in code view so that logic app will run daily

Comment: in that case you can add recurrence before the sharepoint trigger but make sure you use only one sharepoint trigger and not parallel triggers like mentioned in this image https://i.imgur.com/WVNCQ2n.png

Comment: If we add Recurrence as first trigger it will run daily particular timings but what about when a file created in the folder is it run for these case

Comment: @equals(triggerBody()?['{IsFolder}'], false) how can I pass the expression in to my expression @or(startsWith(triggerBody()['{Path}'], 'Shared Documents/source/'),startsWith(triggerBody()['{Path}'], 'Shared Documents/General/')) because these is the only expression is suitable for my requirement

Comment: @James haven't you tried?

Comment: On parse Json what code can I give i saw some code on your picture

Comment: I was just trying to get the path of the sharepoint trigger. So instead of parsing the output you can directly use Folder path variable from the trigger . refer this image https://i.imgur.com/JsdzrnZ.png

Comment: It was excute default values my path is Shared Documents/New/Mar-2023 i was given path in switch condition was Shared Documents/New/ i think we are give month and year also in the path but we ont hard code month and year in switch

Comment: Thats how it works it triggers for every file upload but performs actions only then the condition is satisfied.

Comment: But my end excute default action

Comment: Thats how it will be executed the switch condition will check for the paths you have mentioned.

Comment: Insted of switch can we use condition

Comment: For my case i had maintained year month dates on folder so unable to give in switch i think on condition will give expression so can suggest your solution in condition

Comment: How can can I implement can you suggest implement steps